# AMDGPU-Pro 17.40 failed installation when building kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, amd-graphics

Kernel Version:

```
4.13.0-36-generic
```

System Information:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Here is the crash log below:

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for amdgpu-17.40-514569 for kernel 4.13.0-36-generic (x86_64)
 Fri Feb 23 15:15:30 HKT 2018
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic'
   AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/built-in.o
   AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/built-in.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.o
   AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/built-in.o
   AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/built-in.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_module.o
   AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/built-in.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/ttm_memory.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_device.o
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.c:1:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h: In function ‘kcl_drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:332:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’
   return drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(dev, pipe, max_error, vblank_time,
          ^
 In file included from ./include/drm/drmP.h:83:0,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:6,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.c:1:
 ./include/drm/drm_vblank.h:174:6: note: declared here
  bool drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(struct drm_device *dev,
       ^
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:6:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h: In function ‘kcl_drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:332:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’
   return drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(dev, pipe, max_error, vblank_time,
          ^
 In file included from ./include/drm/drmP.h:83:0,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:6,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:6,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 ./include/drm/drm_vblank.h:174:6: note: declared here
  bool drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(struct drm_device *dev,
       ^
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:6:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h: In function ‘kcl_drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:332:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’
   return drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(dev, pipe, max_error, vblank_time,
          ^
 In file included from ./include/drm/drmP.h:83:0,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:6,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:6,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 ./include/drm/drm_vblank.h:174:6: note: declared here
  bool drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(struct drm_device *dev,
       ^
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:7:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h: In function ‘kcl_reservation_object_copy_fences’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h:95:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘reservation_object_copy_fences’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return reservation_object_copy_fences(dst, src);
          ^
 scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.o] Error 1
 scripts/Makefile.build:581: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl' failed
 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkcl] Error 2
 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_chardev.o
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/ttm_memory.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm/ttm_memory.o] Error 1
 scripts/Makefile.build:581: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm' failed
 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/ttm] Error 2
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_topology.o
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:14:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h: In function ‘kcl_reservation_object_copy_fences’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h:95:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘reservation_object_copy_fences’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return reservation_object_copy_fences(dst, src);
          ^
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:6:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h: In function ‘kcl_drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:332:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’
   return drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(dev, pipe, max_error, vblank_time,
          ^
 In file included from ./include/drm/drmP.h:83:0,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:6,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:6,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 ./include/drm/drm_vblank.h:174:6: note: declared here
  bool drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos(struct drm_device *dev,
       ^
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/../include/../backport/backport.h:14:0,
                  from <command-line>:0:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h: In function ‘kcl_reservation_object_copy_fences’:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_reservation.h:95:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘reservation_object_copy_fences’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return reservation_object_copy_fences(dst, src);
          ^
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.c: At top level:
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.c:814:26: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   .get_vblank_timestamp = kcl_amdgpu_get_vblank_timestamp_kms,
                           ^
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.c:814:26: note: (near initialization for ‘kms_driver.get_vblank_timestamp’)
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.c:815:26: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   .get_scanout_position = kcl_amdgpu_get_crtc_scanoutpos,
                           ^
 /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.c:815:26: note: (near initialization for ‘kms_driver.get_scanout_position’)
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o] Error 1
 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_pasid.o
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o] Error 1
 scripts/Makefile.build:581: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu' failed
 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_doorbell.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_flat_memory.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_process.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_queue.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_mqd_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_mqd_manager_cik.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_mqd_manager_vi.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_mqd_manager_v9.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_kernel_queue.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_kernel_queue_cik.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_kernel_queue_vi.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_kernel_queue_v9.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_packet_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_process_queue_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_device_queue_manager.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_device_queue_manager_cik.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_device_queue_manager_vi.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_device_queue_manager_v9.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_interrupt.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_events.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/cik_event_interrupt.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_int_process_v9.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_dbgdev.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_dbgmgr.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_crat.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_rdma.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_peerdirect.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_ipc.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/kfd_debugfs.o
   LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/amd/amdkfd/amdkfd.o
 Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build' failed
 make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 4.13.0-36-generic
Date: Fri Feb 23 15:15:46 2018
DuplicateSignature: dkms:amdgpu-pro-dkms:17.40-514569:/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/17.40-514569/build/include/kcl/kcl_drm.h:332:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘drm_calc_vbltimestamp_from_scanoutpos’
Package: amdgpu-pro-dkms 17.40-514569
PackageVersion: 17.40-514569
SourcePackage: amdgpu-pro-dkms
Title: amdgpu-pro-dkms 17.40-514569: amdgpu kernel module failed to build
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, under 4.13.0-36-generic driver installation fails and driver doesn't work properly(Steam client crying about bad OpenGL gfx extension).

However, when I boot under 4.13.0-28 all seems fine.

Comment: Please don't post comments in a answer. You will be able to leave comments when you have [earned a reputation of 50](https://askubuntu.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right kernel version is 4.10.

They have removed the requirement from the docs but it is definitely a version that works. 4.11 might work too.